# Trace: sys.argv[:] = args; TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

Try to trace pdb:

python3 -m trace --trace pdb.py helloworld.py

File "~/python362/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1654, in main

```
sys.argv[:] = args
```

I expect sys.argv is a list, but python3 raises an error.

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: A quick workaround is to add sys.argv = list(sys.argv) ahead or enclose RHSs of sys.argv assignments with list(...), but it's just not the right way.

Comment: Even get over this problem, it would not work anyway. Pdb will execute __main__.__dict__.clear() within _runscript that clears the __dict__ of race.py and causes another import error.  I think this is a designated behavior so will delete this post later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, there is a bug in [`trace.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/trace.py#L708):

```
sys.argv = opts.filename, *opts.arguments
```

[Log it](https://bugs.python.org/).

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/436831dbe47e66afb0a4f5927859073015dbd4bb ... Pinging SilentGhost...

Comment: Thanks for so amazingly quick response with code submission. I clone your code, compile and try it with

Comment: justin@ubuntu:/media/justin/LinuxWork/OpenSources/cpython-master/debug$
./python /media/justin/LinuxWork/OpenSources/cpython-master/Lib/trace.py --trace  /media/justin/LinuxWork/OpenSources/cpython-master/Lib/pdb.py ./hello.py

Comment: However, it get the same error. I also check sys.path.  ./python
Python 3.7.0a3+ (default, Dec  7 2017, 14:53:54) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/media/justin/LinuxWork/OpenSources/cpython-master/Lib', '/media/justin/LinuxWork/OpenSources/cpython-master/debug/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7-pydebug', '/home/justin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

Comment: Why would you clone that code? It's evidence of the bug.